# 'AppsFlyerLib/AppsFlyerTracker.h' file not found, Has anyone ever seen this error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After I pod installed `pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'` in my podfile, I import it for use but after I built, It show this error.
Has anyone seen this issue ?

```
'AppsFlyerLib/AppsFlyerTracker.h' file not found
1. Did not find header 'AppsFlyerTracker.h' in framework 'AppsFlyerLib' (loaded from '/Users/apples/trueid-ios-music-tunedglobal-appdemo/Pods/AppsFlyerFramework/iOS')
```

For more info: XCode 11.7, Cocoapod 1.10.0 and I already deintegrate and update my pod.

**Update Solution**

- According @SophySwicz's comment, I found an issue about in AppFlyerLib had a new version of sdk to version 6 but My project still use old API name. For solve this issue, You can migrate api to use v6 or downgrade in your pod to version 5 everything should be ok. ( Thank you for help @SophySwicz )

Comment: Can you give us more information about your project? Xcode 12.1? (which version of xcode you have?). Have you tried to delete Derived Data? have you cleaned before or after a deletion of derived data?  Use the .xcworkspace file to open the project in Xcode, instead of the .xcodeproj file, from this point forward.

Comment: Sorry @SophySwicz I already updated my question. Thank you

Comment: @SophySwicz I tried to clean project and delete xcode derived data, But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of appsFlyer are you installing? check the release notes here https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001224823-AppsFlyer-iOS-SDK-release-notes and this thread is important, it seems that file was renamed https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-react-native-plugin/issues/181

Comment: Glad to help, I'm gonna post it on the answer and would be nice if you add a check as accepted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of appsFlyer are you installing?
check the release notes here https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001224823-AppsFlyer-iOS-SDK-release-notes

**And this thread is important, it seems that file was renamed hence the issue you're having:**
https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-react-native-plugin/issues/181

Answer (score 0):

**Appdelegate.h**

```
   #import <AppsFlyerLib/AppsFlyerLib.h>


   @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate,AppsFlyerLibDelegate>
```

**Appdelegate.m**

```
   [AppsFlyerLib shared].appsFlyerDevKey = @"Nkxxxxxxxxxxxxx6";
   [AppsFlyerLib shared].appleAppID = @"1234567890";
   [AppsFlyerLib shared].delegate = self;
   [AppsFlyerLib shared].isDebug = true;

   - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     // Track Installs, updates & sessions(app opens) (You must include        this API to enable tracking)
     [[AppsFlyerLib shared] start];
     // your other code here....

   }


   // Open Universal Links
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void        (^) (NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
     [[AppsFlyerLib shared] continueUserActivity:userActivity  restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
     return YES;
   }
```